# trying to configure my virtual host files on an apache server for local development on a mac

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost, apache2.4

## trying to configure a virtual host for my project however the server automatically picks up the root directory. Below is what i have configured it to be.

`<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:8080> ServerName project-1.local DocumentRoot "/Users/mac/Projects/project-1/public" <Directory "/Users/mac/Projects/project-1/public"> AllowOverride All Require all granted </Directory> </VirtualHost>`

## However this is what i get when i run apachectl -S

`VirtualHost configuration: 127.0.0.2:8080         project-1.local (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:40) ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd" Main DocumentRoot: "/usr/local/var/www" Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log" Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/var/run/httpd/" mechanism=default PidFile: "/usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid" Define: DUMP_VHOSTS Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG User: name="_www" id=70 not_used Group: name="_www" id=70 not_used`

## What am i doing wrong here?

**this is what my hosts file looks like**
`127.0.0.1       localhost 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost ::1             localhost 127.0.0.2       project-1.local`

i tried changing the vhost file and resaving it however it didnt work

Comment: You really need to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.  Apache will try to find a VirtualHost that has a ServerName or ServerAlias that matches what you put in your browser.  If it cannot find an exact match, it will find the first VirtualHost if found in your configuration, from top to bottom.  Here you would have to ask for `http://project01.local:8080/`

Comment: In each of your VirtualHost, configure logs (Custom and error) that point to a separate file.  This way you see what each VirtualHost does.  You can also increase your LogLevel to see more details.